# Shadow DOM Server-side templating

Tags: javascript, html, css, server-side, shadow-dom

I am interested in upcoming standard called ["Shadow DOM"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-shadow-dom-20121016/) that hasn't default browser support at this time. But how about server-side emulation? I mean something like custom tags in template engine but with internal CSS and JavaScript namespacing that will be compatible with W3C Working Draft so when browsers gonna start to support it - template engine will poop with shadow-dom instead of preprocessed plain html. Also it will be useful if browsers will have different shadow-dom <s>standard</s> understanding. Is there any implementations and is it reasonable at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a client-side JavaScript library, [such as this one,](https://github.com/toolkitchen/polyfills) to emulate Shadow DOM in browsers that do not have native Shadow DOM implementations.

Since the effects of Shadow DOM are seen when manipulating the DOM, a server-side emulation of Shadow DOM doesn’t make a whole lot of sense unless your server is generating pages by manipulating DOM — most server-side frameworks use templating.

Comment: I thought that Shadow DOM goal is solely simplification of source code reading and introducing somу sort of package model.

Comment: @JAre Web Components as a whole will make code simpler and will introduce a package model. Shadow DOM is a specific part of Web Components that is not related to packaging. Shadow DOM can simplify code by making it possible to achieve a better split between content and presentation than is possible with HTML and CSS alone.